# How to get the color of the image pixel on which I clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I have an image, specifically, it's loaded in from `Image.asset()`.

It's wrapped in an extended widget, and has its own context.

I can click on it, and get the local position on which I clicked (x/y local to the image/context).

All I want to do from that point is get some information (specifically, color and alpha/opacity, but color is key). I really just want THAT context's image information, and the ability to definitively say "I need byte #" or "I need pixel info from X and Y". I feel like this HAS to exist in Flutter as it's pretty trivial in many (most?) other platforms with a rich UI.

Am I missing something simple, or is this just harder in this platform than I'm mentally allowing for?

Or should I load the html library and do what I need in there?

Thanks!

(by way of history, I'm fluent in iOS dev, C# and .Net, HTML and canvas work, and a host of other platforms over more years than I want to remember, etc, but fairly new to Flutter because we're doing an emergency rewrite of an app we had in Trigger, which is not behaving well any more. Thanks.) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know if you are still looking for a solution.

I just made [this prototype](https://gist.github.com/roipeker/9315aa25301f5c0362caaebd15876c2f) for you... hope is clear enough.

[Here's a video](https://youtu.be/EJyRH4_pY8I) of the result.

By the way, the image library has plenty of methods to workaround what you need... in case you need it, and pixel values are accessible as List, so you can workaround the KML colors and treat the list as a grid (rows, cols math to find the index).

Warning: the library uses a different color format (#AABBGGRR), but can be converted easily though.

**UPDATE:**

I made a v2 based on the limitations noted in the comments, but change the [original snippet](https://gist.github.com/roipeker/9315aa25301f5c0362caaebd15876c2f) to show both approaches.
This one generates a snapshot of whatever widget you want (so it takes transforms/colorization/box fittings/whatever u have rendered on screen).

Gives you a lot of versatility, if you don't have to animate or invalidate the widget often.

Check the [demo in youtube](https://youtu.be/-LxPcL7T61E).

Comment: O_O

Awesome! Thanks, man! I'm going to work through this and see where mine differs; on quick glance it sure looks close enough. Thanks!!!!

Comment: One hundred percent does EXACTLY what I needed, and I can't seem to control-z enough of my old window to get back to working well enough to compare. I've written, deleted, tweaked, rewritten this so many times... from what I'm seeing, I was pretty close - which I knew I was; I knew it was down to scaling. The streambuilder grabs, essentially, a snapshot of the image as rendered; I think that's where I wasn't getting it done right. HOLY CRAP! THANK YOU!

Comment: PM me your email or something? I'd like to thank you, and add an ack for you in my app. Thanks, man!

Comment: glad to help :) 
idk how to PM n stackoverflow, sorry

Comment: it is not a solution: you are not taking `Image.fit` property into account at all - for example try to use `BoxFit.cover` or `fill` or `none` and it will not work

Comment: You are totally right @pskink, doesn't account for the internal transformations that Flutter does for the image at painting time. 
So, if you need something more complex, you have 2 options in my opinion:
1 - calculate yourself the transformations applied on ur image widget, using the same global key I put in my example, but requesting the widget (and all its current properties) and figuring out the math to match the 1:1 image. 2 - Use the magic of RepaintBoundary widget.

Comment: hint: use [applyBoxFit](http://localhost/flutter/doc-1.6.3/flutter/painting/applyBoxFit.html) top level function

Comment: applyBoxFit helps a little, but doesn't solve the extra you can change in Image, like scale and alignment. Also, what happens when you add a Transform widget for the Image?

Comment: Oh, I tested, and did my own transforms on the base image and the overlay image, and it's all working fine (enough). The registration is off just a hair on the overlay, but it's well within acceptable fudge factors for fingers on the screen vs. the mouse cursor on the regular monitor. In short, good enough is good enough. :D 

@roipeker, my email is chris at chornbe dot com. Shoot me a message some time so I can make sure to connect, and add you as a contributor in the app's "About" page :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add an answer, only available since **September 2020**.

If you need to read image pixels of an image you have in your widget tree, you can use the `ImagePixels` widget from the https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels package (note: I am the author of the package).

Note, you don't need to preload it manually from `Image.asset()`. You just need to provide the `imageProvider`. You need to calculate yourself the relative position from the absolute position given by the GestureDetector:

```dart
// Some (x, y) position you got from the GestureDetector.
var x = 50;
var y = 25;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ImagePixels(
              imageProvider: imageProvider,
              builder: (context, img) =>
                  double xRelative = ... // Calculate from x and img.width;
                  double yRelative = ... // Calculate from y and img.width;
                  Text(
                     "Pixel color is: ${img.pixelColorAt(xRelative, yRelative)}.");
              );
}
```

Comment: How would one do this programmatically, say I have an image which is a square and I need to get the pixel color at the bottom left without physically clicking it. How would one get the x,y position of that pixel on the image?