# Convert a Stack Widget's content to an image

Tags: android, image, svg, flutter, dart

I can overlay images using the Stack Widget in Flutter, but how to convert that overlayed widgets to a real image in png or jpeg format that users can save on their phone?

Context: I want to make a logo maker app, I have image assets in my project, the user may combine these assets to make a logo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RepaintBoundary for that.
Check [this link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb),
regarding saving image to disk, you need to process the bytes taken, you can use the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) (made mostly for dart, but 100% compatible with flutter).

As you see, the code is very simple once you convert the bytes between Flutter Image and image:image

```
new File('thumbnail.png').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(convertedBytes));
```

You can check [this prototype code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488053/8960871) I made yesterday for a similar question regarding reading image pixels in Flutter.

Once you've got the Image bytes, you can stream it to a file in disk (using [path_provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) or similar to find the File's path in each OS), or upload it somewhere, like the first article.

Good luck with the implementation!

Comment: how can we create jpg image? png image is transparent and mixed with background. Please share any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code it takes the screenshot of the screen and save the file in the internal storage.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  # package for saving the screenshot
  image_picker_saver: ^0.1.0
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:image_picker_saver/image_picker_saver.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static GlobalKey screenshotKey = new GlobalKey();     // key
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: RepaintBoundary(
        key: screenshotKey,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Take a screenshot"),
                  onPressed: _takeScreenShot,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _takeScreenShot() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        screenshotKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    print(pngBytes);
    var filePath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: pngBytes);
    print(filePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to take a screenshot of a certain portion of screen

Comment: I have not tried it @RajDhakad

Comment: how can we create jpg image? png image is transparent and mixed with background. Please share any suggestion.