# Flutter: How to get the color of an image pixel?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I have a `Image.asset` in a `GestureDetector`.

With the `onTapDown` I get the coordinates of the pixel touched.

Now, with this coordinates, how I can find the color of the touched pixel? Thanks.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('assets/image/image_1.png',
                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high),
            GestureDetector(
                child: Image.asset('assets/image/image_1_color.png',
                        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                color: Colors.transparent,),
                onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _showDialog(context, details),
            ),
        ]),
    );
}

void _showDialog(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
    
    // get color by coordinates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i provided to a different user:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488053/8960871

If you don’t have fitbox applied, or use a custom blendmode/filter, go with the basic option, to avoid creating a buffer image of the flutter “canvas”, to keep a bettee performance.