# Color of Pixel on Camera Preview with Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve the RGB values for a specific pixel in the camera preview using Flutter. To give an idea as to what the result would look like, I have attached a screenshot of something I built in Java in Android Studio. Once the RGB information is retrieved, the app then does some back-end calculations. I've been through several Flutter camera tutorials, but I have no idea how retrieve the pixel information. Would StreamBuilder be used for this?[image: Pixel information camera preview in Java]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478321/get-the-pixel-on-which-i-clicked/56488053#56488053

Comment: Any solutions for this yet?