# How to get the color of the image pixel with FLUTTER/DART

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, image-processing, colors

I have an image(picked from gallery/camera) and I want to Json or list of colors the all pixels with  Dart/Flutter or any language.
Example:
AnyImageColorMap={"1,1":"AnyColorValue","1,2":"AnyColorValue","1,3":"AnyColorValue",......}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793700/flutter-get-pixel-color-from-image-in-var