# Flutter: How to pick color in an image given the coordinate?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new to flutter and Im developing this app where I want to return a color of an image in a fix coordinate. Any advice of how to do this?, or is there any example or documents you know regarding this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ı understand you want to obtain color depending on images' colors. If I get you right you can [check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478321/how-to-get-the-color-of-the-image-pixel-on-which-i-clicked/56488053#56488053)